# Broad questions create duplicates for more targeted questions (same topic)

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Some time ago, I have asked [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115523/how-to-provide-feedback-about-an-unprofessional-manager-during-the-exit-intervie) which was considered by the community a duplicate of [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14921/how-much-should-i-say-in-an-exit-interview).

My feeling is that the referenced question is too broad as it provides very little context information and any question about a subject (with next to nothing context) that has an [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_interview) is probably too broad for a SE site.

I have little experience with Workplace, but I have seen that similar questions are closed on Politics or SO because those communities want more targeted questions.

Why are such broad questions OK for Workplace? They are not that useful as a more targeted questions on the same matter and can be easily used to create a duplicate stigma on other questions.

**Note:** I have only seen on SO that some *offtopic* question are locked/closed and a special note specifies that they are kept for historical reasons only and should not be used as a reference about what an on-topic question is.

Comment: The top-voted answer on that question is very similar to the top-voted two answers on your question. The second one is similar to your third one (and the one you accepted touches on the same point). Honestly I'm not sure why you think it's *not* a duplicate. Maybe it's *a bit* generic, but we really don't need 50 000 questions all asking slight variations of the same thing, which all have the same answers.

Comment: Actually canonical questions [are pretty much network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical). I know SO has plenty, e.g. [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) (locked because we don't want more answers, not because of "historical reasons"). Although I'm willing to admit the questions here tend to focus very heavily on the specific situation and don't consider much in terms of variations (but that question is not a good example of that).